# Auto Press "Enter" key in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i auto press enter key in dart language for windows platform applications?
Honestly, I couldn't find clear information on this subject.

c# usage:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: better: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/LogicalKeyboardKey-class.html

Answer (score 2):

Use the [win32](https://pub.dev/packages/win32) package. The `sendInput` method is documented here: https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/win32/SendInput.html and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

Typical usage:

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:win32/win32.dart';

void main() {
  final pInputs = calloc<INPUT>(); // allocate an empty input struct
  pInputs.ref.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD; // set the type to keyboard
  pInputs.ref.ki.wVk = VK_RETURN; // set the value to return key
  // see the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput#example
  // for useful ideas

  final rc = SendInput(1, pInputs, sizeOf<INPUT>()); // send the input
  calloc.free(pInputs); // free the allocated memory
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand its usage.

Comment: Check out the readme and its list of examples: https://pub.dev/documentation/win32/latest/index.html

Comment: @RichardHeap, Hello Richard Can you tell me how to create Stacked bar Chart in flutter using JSON data(API)